# How to add string to array in collection | MongoDB | NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a nodeJS app and im using mongoDB to store some data like:
1. usrID,
2. usrName
3. Friends list[is an array]

using nodeJS how do i go to the collection "users" and then add to the array of someone with a specific usrID

This is some code that I have:

```
exports.makeFriendRequest = function(from, to){


mongo.connect(mongoDB, function(err, db) {

if (err) throw err;
var dbo = db.db("My database");
var from = from;
var to = to; //the userID array that we want to change

var collection = dbo.collection('users');

collection.insert(obj);

//dont know what to do here to add to the array


 });


}
```

i have an array with friends for each user and i want to be able to add a string which is another userID to represent that they are "friends" how would i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume you need to add 89 to user 63's document. And your `Friends list` (array) field is `frields_list` and your user id field is `userId`

```
const updateResponse = await collection.updateOne(
    { userId: 63 },
    { $push: { frields_list: 89 } },
)
```